# transition of border when element size changes in jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-trigger

I want to make a smooth transition when I click the button:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
span#l0 {       display: inline-block;
                border:20px solid red;
                transition: all 5s ease !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="l0">Hahahahahahahahahahahahhahahahaha</span>


    <button onclick="document.getElementById('l0').innerHTML='ha'">hura</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make a smooth transition for http://lilaum.com bordered images when turned to text and one image. I do not want a jump which is what it is now, but a 1 second transition. It changes to the Peace refuge text.

Comment: Sure you don't want to add a `blink` tag to go with your 90's era `marque` and auto-play audio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Comment: In particular, this answer seems applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512194/3155639